# Create polygons from points with rectangular buffer in Python

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, polygon-creation, multipoint

I want to create rectangular polygons from points. Actually I have a GeoPandas point DataFrame and the distance in X & Y direction to form the polygon. The distances are equal for every point. I know it is possible to use QGIS or ArcMap, but I look for a method in Python without using this software.

EDIT: it is not a duplicate as far as I can see because the other questions are looking for a square buffer I look for a rectangular buffer with a different size in x, y directions.

EDIT 2: Here is what I have so far

```
import shapely as spl
test_point = [(8.54253101348877, 49.53561782836914)]
distance_lon = 0.010373115539550781 
distance_lat = 0.011997222900390625
spl_polygons = [spl.geometry.Polygon([(x - distance_lon, y - distance_lat), (x + distance_lon, y + distance_lat), (x - distance_lon, y + distance_lat), (x + distance_lon, y - distance_lat)]) for x,y in test_point]
```

The problem is the output looks like:

[image]

not like a rectangular polygon? What am I doing wrong?

Edit 3: The point which form the polygon have to be in the format of (lower left, lower right, upper right, upper left). Now I got the polygon in rectangular format.

Correction of last line:

```
spl_polygons = [spl.geometry.Polygon([(x - distance_lon, y - distance_lat), (x + distance_lon, y - distance_lat), (x + distance_lon, y + distance_lat), (x - distance_lon, y + distance_lat)]) for x,y in test_point]
```

Comment: please post at least a bit of code to show what you have tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating square buffers around points using shapely?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314949/creating-square-buffers-around-points-using-shapely)

Comment: No because I don't want a square polygon ;)

Comment: Buffer twice then envelope both buffers.

Comment: @Leo add some code

Comment: 4th line- you've typed 'sitance ' instead of 'distance'

Comment: @Ofir thx, but the polygon still looks the same because i make the mistake by coding the minimal example, in original code the line was alright

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create the bounding box of each feature you are creating. Take a look at this thread there is a sample on how to achieve that.

[Find bounding box for multiple features using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176170/find-bounding-box-for-multiple-features-using-pyqgis)

You could achieve that  by creating top right point (Xmax,Ymax) and (Xmin,Ymin) and return the bounding box of the collection of the two points. This is the method I would use. However since you have started something and got results just use that resulting object to generate the bounding box.